# USB bluetooth device failed to connect to other device in a VMware virtual os

Tags: bluetooth, vmware-workstation

I am running Vmware vm with Ubuntu 18 OS on a Window 10 system. A USB bluetooth device is plug in this Machine. Now I want to control this bluetooth device in Ubuntu 18 VM, but failed.

In Ubuntu VM, I can get bluetooth hardware info through:

```
# hcitool scan
Scanning ...
    70:EF:00:D0:AE:05   ****
    3C:CD:57:2C:94:4F   ****
    14:DE:39:E5:B2:F8   ****
    48:01:C5:06:DC:A2   ****

# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub


root@turnbig:~# lshw | grep Blue -C 10
                 *-usb:1
                      description: USB hub
                      product: VMware Virtual USB Hub
                      vendor: VMware, Inc.
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: usb@2:2
                      version: 1.00
                      capabilities: usb-1.10
                      configuration: driver=hub slots=7 speed=12Mbit/s
                    *-usb
                         description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                         product: Virtual Bluetooth Adapter
                         vendor: VMware
                         physical id: 1
                         bus info: usb@2:2.1
                         version: 1.00
                         serial: 000650268328
                         capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                         configuration: driver=btusb speed=12Mbit/s
```

But when i try to connect to other BT devices, it failed with "Device 3C:CD:57:2C:94:4F not available", `3C:CD:57:2C:94:4F` is a target bluetooth device to connect:

```
# bluetooth
bluetooth = on

# bluetoothctl
[NEW] Controller 44:AF:28:F5:2B:D3 ***** [default]
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# info 3C:CD:57:2C:94:4F
Device 3C:CD:57:2C:94:4F not available
[bluetooth]# connect 3C:CD:57:2C:94:4F
Device 3C:CD:57:2C:94:4F not available
```

I can connect to this BT device through host machine (Window 10)

thanks for any comment.

Comment: If anyone need more information, please add a comment but not close. I do not know what information is required to fix this, if I know, i would not post this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question fixed, original solution is post [here](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Player/USB-bluetooth-device-failed-to-connect-to-other-device-in-a/m-p/2870169/highlight/false#M37668).

To use a USB bluetooth from VMware guest OS, we can not share bluetooth to guest, we should connect the removeable bluetooth device to guest directly.